# To find oldest record using new record details in database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find oldest device details based on latest device details in oracle database.
All I have is below

**Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE MOBILE_DEVICE (
        IMEI    VARCHAR2(50),
        EFFECTIVE_DATE  DATE,
        EXPIRATION_DATE DATE,
        OLD_IMEI        VARCHAR2(50),
        DEVICE_STATUS   CHAR(1));
```

Record are as below

```
IMEI    EFFECTIVE_DATE  EXPIRATION_DATE OLD_IMEI    DEVICE_STATUS
1004    4/1/2016        12/31/3000      1003        A
1003    3/1/2016        4/1/2016        1002        C
1002    2/1/2016        3/1/2016        1001        C
1001    1/1/2016        2/1/2016                    C
2001    1/1/2016        2/1/2016                    C
2002    2/1/2016        3/1/2016        2001        C
2003    3/1/2016        12/31/3000      2002        A
```

Now I want to retrieve the oldest record for updated device 1004 which is 1001. I am trying to use SQL but I am not able to get the perfect query to achieve my results. (Here IMEI is varchar; assume IMEI could be character string sometimes as per requirement. hence sorting by IMEI is not essential)

Please help me to to find correct SQL query to get desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Hierarchical Query with `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1` to get the last entry:

```
SELECT *
FROM   MOBILE_DEVICE
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH imei = '1004'
CONNECT BY PRIOR imei = old_imei
```

Or, given your data, you can just filter on `NULL` values in `old_imei`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   MOBILE_DEVICE
WHERE  old_imei IS NULL
START WITH imei = '1004'
CONNECT BY PRIOR imei = old_imei
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an hierarchical query to achive that.

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm

```
SELECT *
      FROM MOBILE_DEVICE
      START WITH imei = '1004'
      CONNECT BY PRIOR imei = old_imei
```

Then you can use the above query as a source for another query to retrieve the oldest record.

Comment: Yes, I got the desired results now. I didn't know about oracle hierarchical queries earlier. Thank you very much @pringi